# My object appears jagged with shape keys and subsurf

Tags: modeling, shape-keys, subdivision-surface

So, I made a human face model and tried to animate some basic animations with it using shape keys. I was using subdivision surface to make it appear smooth as well.
(Also, if this could be the problem, I had just assigned everything to an armature)

In the middle of a blink animation, I noticed something strange about the eyelids as they were in mid blink, I paused the playback to see if I was right

And this is what I saw.
[image: Scary, isn't it?]

I turned off subsurf and I saw what it used to look like

[image: Much better, but not smooth :(]

Can I get an answer? I want this done soon, (tomorrow is best).

After doing a little exploration, it seems that the shape keys are only affecting one vertice at a time, and not vertices created by subdivision surface

[image: Even scarier!]

Comment: If you need a fast answer, please upload your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out what the problem is;
So you know the list with all the modifiers on it?

Well, the subdivision has to be on the BOTTOM of the list, I moved it up to be able to access it quickly, but that made it so that it subdivided before the hook modifiers, making it appear jagged!

[image: The fixed version]